# How to get Handle of the Focused Tab in Selenium?

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Selenium for Scrapping purpose for Job Website scrapping. I am ctrl+clicking on jobs to go to second page and scrape details, I somehow wish to keep track of where I clicked to which tab opened up (using a map).
But as soon as I ctrl+click an element, new tab opens and focus changes to that.

`How do I get handle of the current focused tab in Selenium`

I tried

`webDriver.getWindowHandle()`

But it returns me the handle for main tab that I ctrl+clicked an element from.

My Full Code

```
private void openAndMapJobTabs(WebElement jobList) {
        List<WebElement> jobRowsSelector = jobList.findElements(By.tagName("article"));
        for (WebElement jobRow : jobRowsSelector) {
            try {
                ctrlClickElement(jobRow);
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                //the next line is expected by me to give handle of current focused tab
                System.out.println(webDriver.getWindowHandle()); // but this gives me handle of main tab
                webElementToTabMapper.put(jobRow, webDriver.getWindowHandle());
                webDriver.switchTo().window(websiteTabHandle);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("Could Not Click Open Job Tab: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

Actually for me, I need to map elements to the tab they open, so order of tabs are important for me, so I purposely need the handle of current focused tab so I can map it with the element which opened that. But by iterating through all handels, I might mess up the order if any one of the webElement fails to open a new tab or if click is disabled on that.

Any help world be highly appreciated.
Also if there are faster and better tools for scrapping, please recommend.

Comment: Actually for me, I need to map elements to the tab they open, so order of tabs are important for me, so I purposely need a the handle of current focused tab so I can map it with the element which opened that. But by iterating this way, I might mess up the order if any one of the webElement fails to open a new tab or if click is disabled on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the handles of those two tabs or windows, then you have to iterate and switch to the newly opened tab. Try the below code:

```
//      This line will get the handles of the all the tabs or windows and store in a var with type 'Set'
        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        
//      Iterating through the Set - i.e., window handles and switch to the other tab 
        for (String handle : windowHandles) {
//          System.out.println(handle);
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            System.out.println("Title: " + driver.getTitle());
        }
```

If you have more than two tabs or windows, then put the above code the in a method,  pass the window title which you want to switch as a parameter, and compare the title with each window title, once you switch to the expected window, break.

Comment: Actually for me, I need to map elements to the tab they open, so order of tabs are important for me, so I purposely need a the handle of current focused tab so I can map it with the element which opened that. But by iterating this way, I might mess up the order if any one of the webElement fails to open a new tab or if click is disabled on that.

Comment: If you are working with only 2 windows at a time, then you can use the logic of remembering the order of opened windows. If you are working with more than 2 windows at a time, dont go with that logic, it will be a difficult part, switch to each window and check the page title, if the page title is expected, then do the actions. Else, check if anyone of the unique element is displayed or enabled on each page, then do the required actions on that page - to ensure your are on the correct page.

Comment: Thanks for this, It will work for me. But does this mean that by no way you can find the handle of focused tab in selenium ??

Comment: When you open a link in a new tab or window, you can view the newly opened tab on your screen, but selenium will not switch the focus to that tab or window until you use 'driver.switchTo().window()'.